# Modeling sprint and ticket in DDD

Tags: design, domain-driven-design, cqrs, modeling

I'm trying to learn **DDD/CQRS** in a hobby project. And have no prior experience. In this project I use MongoDb as a read db and EventStore as a write db.

I'm building a simple 'Sprint board' application. (JIRA / Asana like)

*Model*

- Sprint
- Tickets

I decided to model this as two separate aggregates. Because I wanted to keep my aggregates small and keep the 'transactional bounderies' as scalable as possible. (Reference: [Vaughn Vernon](https://vaughnvernon.co/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/DDD_COMMUNITY_ESSAY_AGGREGATES_PART_1.pdf))

One of my features I'd like to build in this system is that a sprint can only be closed when every ticket is closed.

It seemed to me as a bad design to load every ticket in memory when deciding if a sprint could be closed.

So I was thinking of a system where a sprint keeps track of the amount of 'created tickets' and 'closed tickets'

- CreateTicketCommand (from FrontEnd)

  - Creates the ticket aggregate

    - Fires TicketCreatedEvent
- TicketCreateEvent gets handeled by a `ProcessManager`

  - Fires a AddTicketToSprint command
- AddedTicketToSprint command gets handeled (Sprint aggregate is retrieved)

  - TicketId is added in a List tickets field on the sprint aggregate.

*time goes by...*

- CloseTicketCommand (from FrontEnd)

  - Retrieve ticket aggregate + Fire TicketStatusChanged event
- TicketStatusChanged gets handeled by a `ProcessManager`

  - Fires a CloseSprintTicket command
- Commandhanlder -> Retrieves sprint aggregate

  - Sets a integer field 'closedTicketAmount' ++

Now when a CloseSprintCommand is fired from the FrontEnd I can check if the `closedTicketAmount` is equal to the amount of tickets in my ticket list is.
If this is not the case I shouldn't be able to close the sprint.

So I got every logic I wanted. But it feels a bit dirty to me.
What if in the future I want a 'Archive' status on my tickets. Than I should check (and so on...)

```
if (tickets.Count > closedTicketAmount + archivedTicketAmount)
    throw new ApplicationException("Sprint cannot be closed when not every ticket is closed");
```

And have the feeling it's probably more correct to load all the ticket aggregates in memory trough a domain service. But have no idea what's a good pattern to load multiple aggregates at once. (Except for a `foreach(){ _repository.Get(a.Id)}`)

I'd like to hear experience from other people.

**So my actual question is:** Am I thinking completely wrong? Inviting my own anti-pattern. Should I just stop thinking and start reading more books.

Btw:

- I ordered the 'red book of DDD'. Maybe this will give my more insights in related problems.
- This is not a question where I'm stuck in my homework / job. [Current non finished code is open-source.](https://github.com/ErazerBrecht/ErazerCQRS)

Sincerely, Brecht

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's actually a yes/no question. As in am I completely thinking it the wrong way or not. Maybe this is a better "question' for in a slack channel or something like that. But I'm not familiar with any at the moment.

Comment: Questions that can be answered with a simple "yes" or "no" are not particularly interesting.  The answer editor won't even allow answers that are less than 30 characters long.

Comment: `Should I just stop thinking and start reading more books?` -- It would be better to write some more code and see where it leads you.  There's nothing like the cold, hard reality of actual code to tell you whether what you're doing is working or not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I totally agree on that one. And it will probably work. (But querying my ReadModel to check if there are still tickets left in a non closed status would also work, and is clearly not the way to go in a future scalable architecture I'd like to learn). My question is probably to broad. And was hoping to find out how someone with experience in the field would solve something like that.

Comment: CQRS embodies one concept, and one concept only: *command methods are kept separate from query methods.* DDD doesn't really concern itself with CQRS; it is an implementation detail.

Comment: If you're going to access the list of tickets for a given sprint ("I can check if the closedTicketAmount is equal to the amount of tickets in my ticket list is. "), why not just get a count of open tickets?

Comment: @JeffO Thx for your time! I'm not accessing the list of tickets of a sprint. I would keep track how many that are closed. Maybe this [example](https://pastebin.com/D5Gc1bRd) makes it a bit more clean what I now have in my head as solution.

I agree that it would actually be nice to have the tickets as child of the sprint. But than I'm having a single bounded context with a single Aggregate root (Sprint). Or what did you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches that will do the job here (you mentioned them both), but I would be hesitant to adopt the method you are proposing - maintaining an `openTicketCount` on your `Sprint`. It has all the makings of premature optimization without justification at the cost of making the system quite a bit more complex.

Let's start by talking about the simplest possible solution: Your `Sprint` holds a reference to all of it's `Tickets`. This solves the problem (and possibly any more that may come up involving a `Sprint` needing knowledge of the composition of its `Tickets`) and also simplifies your event model. The only drawback here is that you will need to load all of the `Tickets` in memory when you want to load a `Sprint`. How many `Tickets` do you suppose will be associated with a `Sprint`? If the number isn't prohibitively large, this shouldn't be of much concern. To me, it seems you will find other reasons to load all of the `Tickets` for a `Sprint` anyway.

If implemented correctly, it should be trivial to optimize your system later to load an `openTicketCount` instead. You mention that this is a hobby project in order to become familiar with DDD. The quality of the design of a system is how easily it can be *changed*, so there is no better way to test your skills than start with a totally un-optimized system and then see how well you can refactor it later on. I know that isn't the most "fun", but it will prepare you for the real world. Continually refactoring towards deeper insight is a cornerstone of DDD.

Another point I want to stress here is that your domain model is *discovered*. Not simply *decided* upon based on the number of Bounded Contexts you want or the Aggregate roots you desire.